# How to share links via FB App when I am offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing an mobile app for iPhone. The app will primary used by people who are on holiday in a different country and will be offline most of the time, due to high costs for internet traffic.

However, the company for which I am developing the app wants to users to be able to use the "Facebook Share" functionality also when people are not connected to the internet.

It should work on a way that they click the SHARE link button in the app, but then get a message that they are offline and the link will get shared as soon as they are online again.

I am trying to figure out how to do this. Can I pass the link I want to share to the official FB App via fb:// protocol (or whatever) and the FB App handles the post/share as soon as it is online again?

Or do I have to do it on my own, put the links I want to share in a internal database and then post them to the wall when I am online again?

Or any other ways??

Any suggestions would be welcome, I would prefer a very quick solution and hope someone maybe has an idea how to do this. I was hoping I can pass the share-link to the official FB App and this one handles everything when it goes online again !?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: I don't know if the FB app will handle it, normally one would store the links in an internal database and then post them when online again as you suggested.

Comment: Short answer: you have to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach should be to make your link-sharing code automatically cache requests until they are sent. The app then doesn't need to concern itself with the details - it can just post the link and get a 'failed', 'success', or 'postponed' response from your API and notify the user accordingly.

Your link-sharing code can then internally check if it can currently post to FB and if not (either because the user is currently offline or perhaps the Facebook token is expired) it will store it for later. This class will then re-check periodically (for example when the app comes to the foreground or when the class is initialised the next time the app starts) for connectivity and then it will check if the token is still valid and perform FB login if required. Once it has a valid token it can then iterate through the pending requests and act upon them.

If you really want to make it nice and clean, you can separate out the code that accepts incoming requests to do something, checks if it can be performed now, does it or stores it for later, and periodically checks any requests in the pending queue. This class will not have any idea what the requests do or how they are performed, it will work with another class that implements a protocol to do the actual work and knows about facebook, etc. There may even be an existing design pattern for such a setup, but I don't know what it's called if there is.

Update: I did some research and found this is very similar to the "Fire-and-Forget Pattern".